# QProcess user privilege elevation

Tags: qt, qt4

Is it possible to start a fully independant process with QProcess with elevated user privilleges?

For example if my c++/qt application is run as a limited user, can my c++/qt application start another independant process with admin rights?

I am implying that the admin username and password is available inside the c++/qt application that is doing the launching of the 3rd party application.

Answer (score 1):

In windows you should create a manifest for your application that specifies the privilege level it needs to run in. Then all you have to do is start the application. You will get a UAC prompt on newer windows version. But that is required and (IMHO) correct. There is no way of going around this.

Under linux you should on installation set a sticky bit to your application with the correct user-rights for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks RedX.  Good info but this doesn't answer my question.  My application doesn't require admin priv.  If it did, I would ask for such priv the way you describe.  My application launches a 3rd party application that requires admin priv and in the question I am trying to avoid manual entry of pass.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way as far as I know but you could start with via the runas command since you do have the password for the administrator account.

In case you don't know the runas command, simply type it in a command shell and it should give you all the information you need.

Comment: runas doesn't quite work right because if i run runas and then supply all the arguments...i can't as far as i know supply password as an argument also.  This means that I get a prompt to enter admin password.  I want to supply that password via my application instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are platform-specific ways to do this, by piping in the input.  In Linux, it's

> system("echo PASS | sudo -u root -S
>   COMMAND");

([source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#101440))  That's for php but should work amywhere.